# Good heuristic for Tron

Tags: artificial-intelligence, voronoi

I have an assigment to do a tron game with AI. Me an my team almost made it but we're trying to find a good heuristic. We taught about Voronoi, but it's kinda slow :

```
for yloop = 0 to height-1
for xloop = 0 to width-1

// Generate maximal value
closest_distance = width * height

for point = 0 to number_of_points-1
  // calls function to calc distance
  point_distance = distance(point, xloop, yloop)

  if point_distance < closest_distance
    closest_point = point
  end if
next

 // place result in array of point types
 points[xloop, yloop] = point

next
next
```

We have 5 seconds to make a move and this algorithm doesn`t sound too good ! I don't need code ... we just need an ideea !
Thank you !

Later edit : Should we try Delaunay Triangulations ?

Comment: Any datastructure that enables you to query fast neighbours is working there. Lookup KD-Trees/Quad-Trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [the postmortem of Google's AI Challenge](http://www.a1k0n.net/2010/03/04/google-ai-postmortem.html) about this.

Comment: I saw that article. doesn`t help us at all :))

Answer (score 1):

well i am considering redesigning my old Wurmeler game (AI including) so i stumped on your question while searching for new ideas so here is my insight from my old AI

- Wurmeler is similar to tron but much slover and worms turn smoothly
- game space is 2D bitmap
- each AI is very simple ... stupid,...
- but navigate better than me
- unless they are closed by other player
- or crush into local min/max
- but still they are fun

OK now the AI algorithm in every decision move:

1. create few rays from Worm

   - one in movement direction
   - few turned to the left by some angle (5 degree step is fine)
   - few turned to the right
2. evaluate the ray length

   - from worm until it hit border
   - or another worm path curve
3. use the max rule to change heading

This old AI maintain only navigation but I want to implement more (this is not yet done):

1. divide map to square sections

   - each section will have the average density of already filled space
   - so if possible AI will choose less filled area
2. add strategies

   - navigate (already done)
   - flee (go away from near player if too close and behind)
   - attack (if on relative parallel course and too close and in the front)
3. may be conversion from raster to vector

   - should speed up the ray traceing and colision detection
   - but with growing length may be slower ... have to try it and see
   - possible use of field algorithms